# Degree of $N$-bit Majority function is larger or equal to $N/2$

Tags: complexity-theory

I am looking to prove that the $N$-bit Majority function $f$, which is 1 if its input $x \in \{0, 1\}^N$
has Hamming weight $> N/2$, and 0 if its input has Hamming weight $\leq N/2$ has degree $\text{deg}f\geq N/2$. We assume that $N$ is even. Any hints or suggestions are most welcome.

Note that an $N$-variate multilinear polynomial $p$ is a function $p: \mathbb{C}^{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ we can write as
$$
p\left(x_{0}, \ldots, x_{N-1}\right)=\sum_{S \subseteq\{0, \ldots, N-1\}} a_{S} \prod_{i \in S} x_{i}
$$
for some $a_{S}\in \mathbb{C}$. The degree of $p$ is defined as $\operatorname{deg}(p)=\max \left\{|S|: a_{S} \neq 0\right\} .$ Moreover, we may use that every function $f:\{0,1\}^{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ has a unique representation as such a polynomial.

Comment: How do you define the degree of a function?

Comment: Definition added :)

Answer (score 2):

I suppose I would start as follows: let
$$
z=\sum_ix_i.
$$
This is simply a variable telling me how many 1s there are. Since this is the only information that I need to determine the function $f$, I should be able to work just with this. There's also an ingredient of symmetry in there, but is maybe not quite of a sufficiently rigorous footing yet.

Having done this, I simply want to find a function $f(z)$ whose value is 0 of $z\leq N/2$. This means it has at least $N/2+1$ zeros, and must have degree at least $N/2+1$. Explicitly, part of the function would be
$$
z(z-1)(z-2)\ldots(z-N/2)
$$
I could construct the whole function by letting
$$
g(z,i)=\frac{\prod_{j=0}^{N}(z-j)}{z-i}
$$
and calculating
$$
f(z)=\sum_{i=N/2+1}^N\frac{g(z,i)}{g(i,i)},
$$
since each term in this sum evaluates to 0 for all values of $z=0,1,2,\ldots,N$ except for the specific term $i$, which evaluates to 1. This is a polynomial of degree no more than $N$, satisfying the values at $N$ points, and hence must be the unique polynomial of no more than degree $N$.

Comment: But is $g(i,i)$ not undefined?

Comment: No because you've already cancelled the $z-i$ terms in both the numerator and denominator.